# Where to see a list of all MediaWiki non-special web pages?

Tags: mediawiki

I get the impression that in MediaWiki there are two main groups of **non-article** and **non-talk** web pages:

1. Special web pages (like `special:categories`)
2. Media-Wiki System web pages (like `media-wiki:common.css`).

While I can see a list of all special web pages under `special:special_pages`, I miss where I can find a list of `media-wiki:media_wiki_pages` (like `media-wiki:common.css`).
Where could I find such list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Special:AllPages` with the namespace filter set to `MediaWiki`. Or use the search box for a prefix search.

Comment: This brings me all pages whatsoever but I need all `media-wiki:media_wiki` ones.

Comment: Fixed a typo in last comment.

Comment: Yeah, it does both. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are after.

Comment: Hello ! I don't need a list of all pages but a list of all the "special-but-not defined-as-special" web pages (like `media-wiki:common.css`). This file (`media-wiki:common.css`) is an example for a **system file** that I just won't find under `Special:special_pages`; but I do need a list containing only "such" system files.

Comment: `MediaWiki:Common.css` is a page. As such `Special:AllPages` does find it.

Comment: I didn't notice the filtering option there with the option "MediaWiki"; you might wanna remind this in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Because comments might be deleted, it's good to add it there, I think...